# Restore appearance fonts

Tags: gnome, fonts

I've installed nerd fonts using its `install.sh` script (I know, a bad idea).

After having installed them, suddently I'm getting this appearance on my gnome desktop:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, font has changed.

I've also took a look on gnome tweaks:

[image]

As you can see, these fonts are ignored.

Any ideas in order to restore default fonts?

Comment: I would read that install script to see what it actually did...and to see if there are uninstall instructions.

Comment: You can help me taking a look on file content [here install.sh](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/install.sh)?

Comment: I'd recommend filing two bug reports on that github page: 1) The installer lack an uninstall option, and 2) The unexpected font behavior you have observed.